# Golang парсинг вложенного JSON с экранированием

Tags: json, golang

Имеется такой не очень красивый JSON:

```
{
  "toComp": "ZZZZ",
  "toFunc": "GETM",
  "retComp": "RWSA",
  "retFunc": "0074",
  "type": "PMM ",
  "class": 160,
  "flags": 2048,
  "transId": 104342,
  "compTransId": 873,
  "completionStamp": 1549389640,
  "timestamp": 1549389640,
  "udata": "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
  "priority": 0,
  "fics": {
    "PATH": "MO:smp1:TM_A:Transactions:counters:ok",
    "MO": "MO{:smp1{:TM_A{:Transactions{:counters{:ok{i time=1549389640,i value=1656329260:stats{:\"10 sec\"{i i_end=1549389650,i i_len=10,f level=1656329216,i max=67916,i min=0,i offset=1656329260,i type=1,f value=51267:}\"60 sec\"{i i_end=1549389660,i i_len=60,f level=1655993472,i max=68330,i min=0,i offset=1655993418,i type=1,f value=508104:}}}}}}}}",
    "JMO": "{\"MO\":{\"smp1\":{\"TM_A\":{\"Transactions\":{\"counters\":{\"ok\":{\"time\":1549389640,\"value\":1656329260,\"stats\":{\"10 sec\":{\"i_end\":1549389650,\"i_len\":10,\"level\":1656329216.0,\"max\":67916,\"min\":0,\"offset\":1656329260,\"type\":1,\"value\":51267.0},\"60 sec\":{\"i_end\":1549389660,\"i_len\":60,\"level\":1655993472.0,\"max\":68330,\"min\":0,\"offset\":1655993418,\"type\":1,\"value\":508104.0}}}}}}}}}",
    "TIMESTAMP": "1549389640"
  }
}
```

Нужно fics взять, далее JMO->MO->smp1->TM_A->Transactions->counters->processed->stats->60 sec->value

Удалось вытащить значение ключа JMO:

```golang
jsonParsed, err := gabs.ParseJSON(response)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

value := jsonParsed.Path("fics.JMO").Data().(string)

data := make(map[string]interface{})

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%v", data)
```

Вывод:

```
map[MO:map[smp1:map[TM_A:map[Transactions:map[counters:map[ok:map[value:1.65632926e+09 stats:map[60 sec:map[i_len:60 level:1.655993472e+09 max:68330 min:0 offset:1.655993418e+09 type:1 value:508104 i_end:1.54938966e+09] 10 sec:map[value:51267 i_end:1.54938965e+09 i_len:10 level:1.656329216e+09 max:67916 min:0 offset:1.65632926e+09 type:1]] time:1.54938964e+09]]]]]]]
```

Подскажите, как далее эффективно и правильно вытащить интересующее меня значение?

Comment: А чем-же он простите такой некрасивый? Вполне себе валидный JSON

Answer (score 0):

Какой JSON, такой и код:

```golang
func main() {
    b := body{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(data)).Decode(&b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    jmo := jmo{}
    err = json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(b.Fics.JMO)).Decode(&jmo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(jmo.MO.SMP1.TMA.Transactions.Counters.OK.Stats["60 sec"].Value)
}
```

Полный рабочий код: https://play.golang.org/p/AOQCuSGD3lz.